# How to configure custom analyzer for elasticsearch-persistence in ruby?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I am trying to index plain ruby objects (non-ActiveRecord) that contain HTML text using `elasticsearch-persistence`. I read about [html strip char filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html#analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter) (or other custom filter) but have not found a straight-forward example of using them in ruby. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780346/html-strip-in-elastic-searc) shows hot to configure the analyzer via the API, but I'm hoping to use the ruby DSL.

How can I create an index that uses this analyzer in ruby?

```
{
   "index" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "analyzer" : {
            "html" : {
               "filter" : [
                  "standard",
                  "lowercase",
                  "stop",
                  "asciifolding"
               ],
               "char_filter" : [
                  "html_strip"
               ],
               "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a helpful post "[Getting Fancy with ElasticSearch](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/getting-fancy-with-elasticsearch/)" by Bree Stanwyck.

> Gems like Tire make setting up ElasticSearch a breeze, but setting up more advanced indexes and interfacing with ActiveRecord can sometimes be a pain. Read on to see how to make your life easier with ElasticSearch and Tire.