# How to filter out (broken) HTML Tags in ElasticSearch's Highlights?

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm having trouble with the ElasticSearch Grails Plugin,
namely the highlighting Feature.

It is returning text with HTML tags, which would not be a big problem, but it is returning broken, cut-off HTML tags as well.

i.e. "`href=google.de> Link <a`"

Those can't be easily filtered out with a RegEx.

The solution to this seems to be a custom analyzer like this:

```
'{
   "index" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "analyzer" : {
            "test_1" : {
               "char_filter" : [
                  "html_strip"
               ],
               "tokenizer" : "standard"
            },
            "test_2" : {
               "filter" : [
                  "standard",
                  "lowercase",
                  "stop",
                  "asciifolding"
               ],
               "char_filter" : [
                  "html_strip"
               ],
               "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

From [HTML Strip in Elastic Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780346/html-strip-in-elastic-search)

The question is how do i get the above into the GRAILS elasticsearch plugin ?
(or any other solution for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

try to use:
"number_of_fragments": 0

which will return all the content